# FCM Status bar icon not showing

Tags: android, firebase, ionic2, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to add a white icon for push notifications sent via FCM admin. Per the guides [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages#webpush_specific_fields), I should be able to just add in the "icon" key and its corresponding URL to the notification. However, it is not working. My default app Icon gets used instead when the notification is received on my phone. Any idea why it's not working? Here is my code

```
    var message = {
    notification: {
        title: "title here",
        body: "body message here"
    },
    android: {
        notification: {
            "sound": "default",
            "click_action": "FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",
            "icon": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/xxxxx"
        }
    },
    data: {
        tab: "message",
        subsection: "notification"
    },
    token: registrationToken
};

// send the push notification
var sentMessage = admin.messaging().send(message)
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log("Successfully sent message: ", response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error sending message: ", error);
    });
```

Comment: anyone? let me know if I need to add more details in for clarification, or if I did not ask my questions right. Trying to figure out what to do to get responses.

Comment: adding a comment in here one more time, to see if I can get a response